# InputNumber for a currency input?

Tags: antd

I need a currency amount input. Is there anyway to customize the InputNumber to support things like commas (',') or $?

Similar to these:

http://leonardowf.github.io/react-simple-currency/

https://github.com/jsillitoe/react-currency-input

I'm using form and InputNumber right now but it is hard to read (for the user) without at least the commas per thousand:

```
<Col span='24'>
   <FormItem label='Original Investment'>
         {getFieldDecorator('originalInvestment', {
           rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Investment!' }],
           initialValue: 100000000
         })(
            <InputNumber min={100000000} max={10000000000} />
         )}
   </FormItem>
</Col>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported yet, you can trace https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4681

Answer (score 3):

you can use the formatter property to achieve this

```
<InputNumber
  defaultValue={1000}
  formatter={value => `$ ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')}
  parser={value => value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, '')}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

check https://ant.design/components/input-number/#components-input-number-demo-formatter for more

Answer (score 0):

Use this library. It's well maintained and it's well tested
https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format.
I tried quite a bit of libraries. This fixed my problem

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. He wants the `InputNumber` to include the formatting